# How to configure DPT in eclipse to use with Xampp

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp

I'm working in Ubuntu with eclipse for development PHP, with PDT (PHP Development Tool), and using Xampp and my workspace is at /home/, so when I run my PHP file it run under http://localhost/, but the files are not in the folder /opt/lampp/htdocs, so there is a way to copy the files to /opt/lampp/htdocs when I run my project from eclipse??

Answer (score 1):

simply copy the int13_svn.dll from xampp/apache/bin to the php-directory of xampp i.e. xampp/php

Comment: sorry but I'm working in ubuntu, so there isn't a file int13_svn.dll